# Python- Drop Down Change Content color

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, drop-down-menu, plotly-dash

I am trying to change the dropdown content list background color to green in style in Python Dash, i am unable to do so. Can someone help me? I am new to CSS.

```
dcc.Dropdown(
                        id = 'business_area_dropdown',
                        options=[
                            {'label': 'Academia', 'value': 'academia'},
                            {'label': 'Energy', 'value': 'energy'},
                            {'label': 'Research', 'value': 'research'}
                        ],
                        placeholder="Select Business Area",
                        style = {"background-color":"green"}
                        width = '40%',
                        display = 'inline-block',
                        verticalAlign = "middle"
                        )
                    )
```

Comment: What have you tried? And also please provide a [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 4):

You should specify your css style in a css file inside an `assets` directory. According to [this post](https://community.plot.ly/t/dash-core-components-dss-styles/21621/4), you could create:

1. an `app.py` file:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(dcc.Dropdown(id = 'business_area_dropdown',
                                   options=[{'label': 'Academia', 'value': 'academia'},
                                            {'label': 'Energy', 'value': 'energy'},
                                            {'label': 'Research', 'value': 'research'}],
                                   placeholder="Select Business Area",),)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server()
```

2. a directory `assets`, and a css file `style.css` inside:

```
#business_area_dropdown .VirtualizedSelectFocusedOption {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

And you get:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer Sentence. The result you have displayed still has the drop-down list content area as white. Say I want to change that to grey which part I should add to the assets CSS file to change it?

Comment: Do you want the default background color for 'Academia', 'Energy', and 'Research' to be gray?

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
#business_area_dropdown .Select, .Select div, .Select input,.Select span { 
background: #yourcolor  /*to change the background color of the options*/
color: #yourcolor  /*to change the color of the options */
}
```

It should change all the background of the DropDown element